# Add intermediate model fields to reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two related models (Product and Recipe). There is a many-to-many relationship defined between them (with a `through` model). I am able to query the 'through' model fields using the below serializer, but I am unable to make this work the other way around (from Product to Recipe)

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    displayname = models.CharField(max_length=50,validators=[alphanumeric])
    ...

class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='RecipeInput', related_name='recipe_input')
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='RecipeOutput',related_name='recipe_output')

class RecipeInput(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    amount_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class RecipeOutput(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    amount_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    mj = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class RecipeInputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.id')
    product_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.displayname')

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeInput
        fields = ('product_id',"product_name", 'amount', 'amount_min', )

class RecipeOutputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.id')
    product_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.displayname')

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeOutput
        fields = ('product_id',"product_name", 'amount', 'amount_min', 'mj', )

class ProductInputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    recipe_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='recipe.id')
    recipe_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='recipe.displayname')

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeInput
        fields = ('recipe_id','recipe_name', 'amount_min', 'amount', )

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = RecipeInputSerializer(source='recipeinput_set', many=True)
    products = RecipeOutputSerializer(source='recipeoutput_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products_in = ProductInputSerializer(source='recipe_input', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

Now, this works for Recipe, I get the following output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1239,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "product_id": 1787,
                "product_name": "Automated Wiring",
                "amount": 15,
                "amount_min": 7.5
            },
            {
                "product_id": 1799,
                "product_name": "Circuit Board",
                "amount": 10,
                "amount_min": 5.0
            }
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "product_name": "Adaptive Control Unit",
                "amount": 2,
                "amount_min": 1.0,
                "mj": 3300.0
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 1240,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "product_id": 1809,
                "product_name": "Copper Sheet",
                "amount": 5,
                "amount_min": 25.0
            },
            {
                "product_id": 1871,
                "product_name": "Quickwire",
                "amount": 20,
                "amount_min": 100.0
            }
        ],
        "products": [
            {
                "product_name": "AI Limiter",
                "amount": 1,
                "amount_min": 5.0,
                "mj": 180.0
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

But, for Product, I am not able to query the related model (Recipe) and the values of the through model. In the serializers.py I defined `products_in` but it doesnt show recipe_id, recipe_name, etc.

```
[
    {
        "id": 2541,
        "products_in": [
            {
                "amount_min": null
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": 2542,
        "products_in": [
            {
                "amount_min": null
            },
            {
                "amount_min": null
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Try using `recipe_input` instead of `products_in` and omit `source=...`

Comment: tried that, same result